# How to launch a init file and shell script file in docker file CMD when using centos/systemd as base image?

Tags: linux, image, docker, containers

My base image is `centos/systemd.so` my cmd will contain `/usr/sbin/init` but i also want to run a shell script file when the container gets created.

my Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos/systemd

#RUN yum -y install dos2unix


CMD ["usr/sbin/init"]   //here i also want to launch a shell script file
```

Comment: What have you already tried?  Do you _need_ systemd, and if so, why?  The other obvious alternative is to recast your script into a systemd unit file.

Comment: @DavidMaze init is a binary file so we cannot recast my script into init file of systemd.I nedd systemd to start some processes and many other reasons are there for systemd

Answer (score 1):

Edit with the solution:

```
FROM centos/systemd 

ADD /path-to-hello/hello.sh ./ 
ENTRYPOINT ["./hello.sh"]
```

The last line in `hola.sh` is `exec /usr/sbin/init`

Build docker: `docker build -t DockerImageName:1.0 .`

Run docker: `docker run --name DockerName DockerImageName:1.0`

Comment: can u give a detailed explanation of using --init.my use case is i need to run /usr/sbin/init and a shell script file both when container gets created but docker file can have only one cmd

Comment: I think you need to use the `ENTRYPOINT`, not `CMD`. The last line in your script can be `exec /usr/sbin/init` and with this you can run your script and `/usr/sbin/init` when the container is created.

I think you need to use the `ENTRYPOINT`, not the` CMD`. The last line in your script can be `exec / usr / sbin / init` and with this you can execute your script and` / usr / sbin / init` when the container is created.

Comment: assume my shell file name is hello.sh and service is /usr/sbin/init how to run both when a container gets created

Comment: `FROM centos/systemd
ADD /path-to-hello/hello.sh ./
ENTRYPOINT ["./hello.sh"]`
The last line in hola.sh is `exec /usr/ sbin/init`

Build docker: `docker build -t DockerImageName:1.0 .`
Run docker: `docker run --name DockerName DockerImageName:1.0`